# Path error with Paperclip and JRuby on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, jruby

I'm learning about [Paperclip: Attaching Files in Rails](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html)

I place these code to display image on show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url %>
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:thumb) %>
```

On new page, I browse a file (.png) from my computer and click create.
Then I got the error

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

How to solve this problem? Please help!

When I check on development.log. I found these errors:

```
>Status: 500 Internal Server Error
    The system cannot find the path specified
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/utils.rb:486:in
    initialize'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/utils.rb:486:in
    new'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/utils.rb:486:in
    parse_multipart'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/utils.rb:471:in
    loop'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/utils.rb:471:in
    parse_multipart'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/request.rb:268:in
    parse_multipart'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/request.rb:146:in
    POST'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in
    run'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in
    each'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in
    call'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:67:in
    process'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in
    process_client'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in
    each'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in
    process_client'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in
    run'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in
    initialize'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in
    new'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in
    run'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in
    initialize'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in
    new'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in
    run'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:38:in
    run'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:31:in
    require'
    C:/jruby/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
    require'
    ./script/server:3
    ./script/server:2:in `load'
    -e:2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the paperclip gem for quite awhile, and I think its awesome - So don't lose heart!

Here's a couple of things I can think of:

(1) Could you show us your User model code?

(2) Did you accept PNG files as a valid image file? Something like this:

`validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your upload directory is not valid.
The message you get is a Windows error message.
You need to specify a correct upload path for you pictures in your model.
For example:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
    :url  => ":style/:basename.:extension",
    :path  => ":style/:basename.:extension",
    :storage => :filesystem
```

I hope it helps.